# ¿Qué correo va en los headers de un formulario?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda sobre la parte de Headers de un formulario que he creado en PHP: ¿Qué correo va en los headers?

Código PHP:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Y dentro de mi mail, la forma correcta de poner el mail ¿cuál es?

Esta:

```
$resultado= @mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

O esta:

```
$resultado= mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es para que te llegue informacion al correo o para manejarlo localmente ?

```
<?php
$destino= "ajae_amm@hotmail.com";
$contacto="Xeoms";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"]; 
$contenido = "nombre :". $nombre . "\nCorreo :" . $email . "\nmensaje :" . $mensaje;
mail($destino, "contacto", $contenido);
header("Location:contacto.html");

?>
```

Comment: Para que me llegue a un correo.

Comment: <?php
$destino= "xxxxxxx@hotmail.com";
$contacto="Xeoms";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"]; 
$contenido = "nombre :". $nombre . "\nCorreo :" . $email . "\nmensaje :" . $mensaje;
mail($destino, "contacto", $contenido);
header("Location:contacto.html");

?>

Comment: con esto lo haces las variables post el nombre de quien envia su correo y mensaje